# Check a post published date if its more than two years old

Tags: php, wordpress

I am displaying the "Date" when a post is published using this code get_the_date();

but I would like to not display the date if the posts is more than two years old

Here is the logic

```
if (get_the_date() < 2 years) {
    echo 'Do not display date';
} else {
    echo 'Display date';
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried? and what is the problem of your code? PHP have a function called `date_diff()`. have you tried that? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php

Comment: You'd be best off just querying for post older than 2 years. Not sure how to do that with WP though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did and worked

```
if( strtotime( $post->post_date ) < strtotime('-2 years') ) {
    echo 'old posts';
} else {
    echo 'new posts';
}
```